# x-editable for bootstrap source selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I have the following x-editable code working:

```
      <td>
          <a href="#" class="xeditable" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-emptytext="Assign" data-placement="right" data-resource="workorder" data-source="/employees.json?workgroup=<%= workorder.workgroup.id %>" data-name="employee_id" data-url="/workorders/<%= workorder.id %> " data-original-title="Select Employee">
                <% if workorder.employee_id != nil %>
                    <%= workorder.employee.try(:employee_full_name) %>
                <% end %>
           </a>
      </td>
```

I want to add `?archive=false` to the data-source.

This didn't work:

```
data-source="/employees.json?archive=false?workgroup=<%= workorder.workgroup.id %>"
```

How can I code this?

Comment: did you mean to use
`data-source="/employees.json?archive=false&workgroup=<%= workorder.workgroup.id %>"` (& instead of ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably meant to use

```
data-source="/employees.json?archive=false&workgroup=<%= workorder.workgroup.id %>"
```

(& instead of ?)